# How can I further improve this code to follow the standards?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react. I'm facing the following issue in my code:

1. Within the function addCard, why do I need to call setState ? If I don't call the setState the card is not added.
2. I have read that mutating the state is not good in react. So one should use libraries such as immutable.js. I want an opinion on whether this code follows the standard practices of React ( without delving into redux).

---

```
            import React, {Component} from 'react';
            import ReactDom from 'react-dom';



            class App extends React.Component{
                constructor(){
                    super();
                    this.state = {
                        name: '',
                        desc:'',
                        data : [
                                {
                                    name: 'Batman',
                                    desc:'I\'m Batman'
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'Superman',
                                    desc: 'Up up and away'
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'Spiderman',
                                    desc: 'Your friendly neighbour'
                                }
                            ]
                        }

                        this.updateStateName =this.updateStateName.bind(this);
                        this.updateStateDesc =this.updateStateDesc.bind(this);
                        this.addCard =this.addCard.bind(this);

                    }
                    updateStateName(e) {
                      this.setState({name: e.target.value});
                    }

                    updateStateDesc(e) {
                      this.setState({desc: e.target.value});
                    }

                    addCard(){
                        this.state.data.push({
                            name: this.state.name,
                            desc: this.state.desc
                        })
                        let cards = this.state.data;

                        this.setState({
                            data: cards,name: '',desc: ''});

                    }

                    render(){
                        return(
                          <div>
                          <h3>Simple Form</h3>
                          <Form name={this.state.name}
                          desc={this.state.desc}
                          updateStatePropName={this.updateStateName}
                          updateStatePropDesc={this.updateStateDesc}
                          addCard={this.addCard}/>
                          <hr/>
                          <Content_Card data={this.state.data}/>
                          </div>
                        );
                    }
            }

            class Form extends React.Component{
                constructor(props){
                    super(props);

                }




              render(){
                return(
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Title" value={this.props.name} onChange={this.props.updateStatePropName}/>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Desc" value={this.props.desc} onChange={this.props.updateStatePropDesc} className="desc-box"/>
                        <br/>
                        <button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.addCard()}> Add New Card </button>
                    </div>
                );
              }
            }

            const Content_Card = (props) => {

                return(
                  <div>
                  <Card listData = {props.data}/>
                  </div>
                )
            }

            const Card = (props) =>{
              const card = props.listData.map( (item) => {
               return <li className="content-card" key={item.name}>
                <h4>{item.name}</h4>
                <div>{item.desc}</div>
                </li>
              });
                return(
                    <div>
                  <ul>{card}</ul>
                    </div>
                )
            }


            ReactDom.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Within the function addCard, why do I need to call setState ? If I don't call the setState the card is not added.

From the documentation [setState()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state".

Adding an item to the cards array does not tell React that the component needs to be re-rendered.

> 2) I have read that mutating the state is not good in react. So one should use libraries such as immutable.js. I want an opinion on whether this code follows the standard practices of React ( without delving into redux).

Because of the nature of `setState`, mutating `this.state` is not good because take your code for example:

```
this.state.data.push({name: this.state.name, desc: this.state.desc})
```

`push` modifies the `data` directly which circumvents React's state management and calling `setState` may end up replacing the mutation you just made on `data`.

Instead of using `push` which mutates the data directly, you can use `concat` which creates a copy of the array instead of modifying the original. Your code would end up looking like:

```
addCard(){
  this.setState({
    data: this.state.data.contact({
      name: this.state.name, desc: this.state.desc
    }), 
    name: '', 
    desc: ''
  });
}
```

You must be aware that for more complex objects, making a shallow copy is still not enough as references are passed when copying.